# How do I stop an "iframe" from showing previously loaded (old) content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm having problem with `iframe`/pop-up showing old content.

I only have one `iframe` tag and then change the `src` of it with JavaScript to show different image albums.

So when you click the album name the `src` is changed and then trigger the pop-up.

Lets say you start opening album 1 then it loads nicely and no problem.

Then when you open the next album (album 2) then pictures from `album 1` are shown for the first 3-7 seconds before the pictures from `album 2` are shown.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <iframe class="iframe" id="iframeurl" src="lpading.gif" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function showdiv() {             
  document.getElementById('iframeurl').src = data.nurl;
  $("#gluggi1").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Are the src image files big?

Answer (score 0):

It sound lika normal behaviour due to loading the content. You can empty the iframe before you load the new content:

```
$('#iframeurl').attr('src', 'about:blank');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lapskaus ,  this dosn't seem to work though.

I tried to set it about:blank when the popup/iframe is closed so it should be clean before new popup is opened but it's not working.

Comment: As far as i know there are some issues with loading sources to an invisible iframe.Can you try to clear your iframe without closing the popup